# functionality about scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

There are few documents about scala's macro on the web.
There are few cases below I want to how to implement them with scala macro.
Since they are just samples, please don't ask the reason why I want them.
Please consider the code below as pseudo-code.

**1 print type**

```
def add[T1,T2](a:T1,b:T2) = {
  if (a.type == b.type) println(b.type.name)  // determinated at compiling time
  a+b
}
```

**2 generate functions for each type**

```
val typelist = [ Int,Double ]
def mul5(x:T) = x*5
// I want to have mul5 for each type in the typelist. i.e.
def mul5(x:Int) = x*5
def mul5(x:Double) = x*5
```

**3 literal substitution, like macro in C**

```
def hello(x) = for ( i <- x ) println(i) // a macro named hello
// use hello to substitute following code
hello(List(1,2,3,4)) // the generated code should be  for ( i <- List(1,2,3,4) ) println(i)
hello(List("123","123","xx","yy"))
```

Comment: not an answer (your real needs may differ as you request it to be in compile-time) - just to mention: first two can be implemented without macros: 1) TypeTag 2) @specialized annotation. Due to type inference 3rd example will work if you mention `x: List[Any]`

Comment: and for the second option you will need macro-annotations from macro-paradise library

Comment: @dk14 hi, I ask the first question because I want to see how to get the "type" with macro.

Comment: Every macro argument is a Tree or a wrapper thereof. Every Tree has a method Tree.tpe, which can be used to get to its type.

Comment: 3) Here's an example of a similar thing: https://github.com/scalamacros/macrology201/tree/part1.